# Write into html with Angular pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I have a pipe that returns an array of elements that have the hashtag

```
arr=''
spl!:string;
transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) {
   this.arr=''
   this.spl = value.split(' ')
   for (const iterator of this.spl) {
       if(iterator.charAt(0)==='#'){
        this.arr=value
        console.log(iterator);
       }

   }
    return this.arr;
}
```

in my ts file, I'm adding a text into the function

```
  this.noteService.getNoteById(this.queryParam).subscribe((res)=>{
  this.noteModel = res
  this.noteData = res.note
  this.textValue=Object(this.noteData).text
  this.textValue= this.format.transform(this.textValue) //this is the pipe
  this.textForm.controls['text'].setValue(this.textValue)// here I'm writing into textarea
})
```

The functions returns all tags, how can I add the tags in span tag and write text in textarea?

Comment: Looks like your pipe returns only the last tag instead of an array of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For display text in textarea you can bind the `textValue` variable to the textarea like this (more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding)):

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="textValue"></textarea>
```

For display tags separately (more about [pipes usage](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#using-a-pipe-in-a-template) and [iteration in templates](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#repeating-a-component-view)):

```
<div class="tags">
  <span *ngFor="let tag of textValue | tags">{{ tag }}</span>
</div>
```

You can write a pipe this way:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'tags'
}) class TagsPipe {

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) {
    return value?
      .split(' ')
      .filter(w => w.startsWith('#');
  }
}
```

In your component:

```
this.noteService.getNoteById(this.queryParam).subscribe((res) => {
  this.noteModel = res;
  this.noteData = res.note;
  this.textValue = (this.noteData as any).text;
});
```